# What header file do I need for MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification?

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I don't know what header file I should include.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(loadStateDidChange:) name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

Error: undeclared identifier MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification

Sorry, I find solution

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html states `MPMoviePlayerController.h` right there in the docs (quote):

*MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification
Notifies observers that the network buffering state changed. The affected movie player is stored in the object parameter of the notification. There is no userInfo dictionary. The current load state can be retrieved from the loadState property of the movie player controller.*

*Availability
Available in iOS 3.2 and later.*

*Declared In
MPMoviePlayerController.h*

Do a search on the iOS dev center once or twice, things like these are almost always there ;-)